# Uniqueness of the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

With a given linear transformation, does all the matrix representation of the transformation have the same characteristic polynomial?

Two similar matrices have the same  characteristic polynomial do two matrices representation of the same linear transformation are similar?

Answer (score 3):

Yes they have the same characteristic polynomial since they are similar:
$$\det(PAP^{-1}-xI)=\det(PAP^{-1}-xPP^{-1})=\det(P(A-xI)P^{-1})\\=\det(P)\det(P^{-1})\det(A-xI)=\det(A-xI).$$

Comment: Can we say that every two similar matrices are representing the same linear transformation?

Comment: Yes they represents the same linear transformation in different basis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because if $A$ is the matrix of endomorphism $u$ in some basis, it is the determinant of endomorphism $u-\lambda \operatorname{id}$, and the determinant of an endomorphism is independant of the basis.